# How to access this json object from handlebarsjs

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, handlebars.js

How to access this json object from handlebarsjs

```
    [ {
    "id" : 9,
    "name" : "Name1",
    "address" : "address1",
    "city" : "city1",
    "state" : "KS",
    "zip" : "11111",
    "country" : "USA",
    "fax" : "111111",
    "phone" : "1111111",
    "website" : "",
    "account" : "11111",
    "contacts" : []
}, {
    "id" : 12,
    "name" : "Name2",
    "address" : "address2",
    "city" : "city2",
    "state" : "NJ",
    "zip" : "11111",
    "country" : "USA",
    "fax" : "",
    "phone" : "1111",
    "website" : "",
    "account" : "11111",
    "contacts" : [ {
        "firstName" : "name",
        "lastName" : "lastname",
        "title" : "rep",
        "phone" : "3333",
        "email" : "33333"
    } ]
} ]
```

I have tried {{name}} to access name but that didn't work, so how do i access name attribute, and the nested firstName attribute under contacts?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to index into the array first in order to get the name. Something like:

```
{{listObj[0].name}}

{{listObj[0].contacts.firstName}}
```

Comment: Do i have to keep track of the index, i thought that all i have to do is putting the template <tr>
    <td>{{name}}</td>
    <td>{{phone}}</td>
    <td>{{fax}}</td>
   </tr>

Comment: I got this error: Error: Parse error on line 9:
...>   <tr>    <td>{{ID[0].name}}</td>  
---------------------^
Expecting 'ID', got 'undefined'
http://localhost:8080/LocalApp/scripts/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js
Line 194

Comment: You cannot use [] notation in Handlebars templates.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a javascript variable name to your JSON object.

```
   var jsonstring = [ {
        "id" : 9,
        "name" : "Name1",
        "address" : "address1",
        "city" : "city1",
        "state" : "KS",
        "zip" : "11111",
        "country" : "USA",
        "fax" : "111111",
        "phone" : "1111111",
        "website" : "",
        "account" : "11111",
        "contacts" : []
    }]
```

Then you can do **jsongstring[0].name**

You can use a for loop to loop over the JSON and print out the information you need

```
for ( var x = 0; x < jsonString.length; x++){
alert(jsonString[x].name);
alert(jsonString[x].contacts.firstName);
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck: your question is explained pretty clearly on the Handlebars documentation page:

http://handlebarsjs.com/

Just scroll down to the "Handlebars Paths" section, and you'll see it talks about exactly what you're looking for ("Handlebars also supports nested paths, making it possible to look up properties nested below the current context ...")