# How do I access a nested json object

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jsrender

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access this json object from handlebarsjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586459/how-to-access-this-json-object-from-handlebarsjs)

I have this json file:

```
[{         
     "id" : 9,
     "name" : "Name1",
     "address" : "address1",
     "city" : "city1",
     "state" : "KS",
     "zip" : "11111",
     "country" : "USA",
     "fax" : "111111",
     "phone" : "1111111",
     "website" : "",
     "account" : "11111",
     "contacts" : []
 }, 
 {
     "id" : 12,
     "name" : "Name2",
     "address" : "address2",
     "city" : "city2",
     "state" : "NJ",
     "zip" : "11111",
     "country" : "USA",
     "fax" : "",
     "phone" : "1111",
     "website" : "",
     "account" : "11111",
     "contacts" : [ {
         "firstName" : "name",
         "lastName" : "lastname",
         "title" : "rep",
         "phone" : "3333",
         "email" : "33333"
     } ]
} ]
```

I can access these attribute

```
<td>{{:name}}</td>
<td>{{:phone}}</td>
<td>{{:city}}</td>
```

But how do I access `contacts.firstName` from the template?

Comment: I'll just whip out my crystal ball here! And all of the sudden I see your entire templating system, and the answer is `<td>{{:contacts.firstName}}</td>` ???? More seriously, who knows, it depends on the templating system used ?

Comment: tried it didnt work, and i coudnt see examples from the JsRender about this

Comment: well, it's really an array, so maybe `<td>{{:contacts[0].firstName}}</td>`

Comment: Didn't you [just recently ask this same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586459/how-to-access-this-json-object-from-handlebarsjs)?

Comment: Yep, seems like a dup of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586459/how-to-access-this-json-object-from-handlebarsjs).

Answer (score 0):

Your contacts are an array. So if you want the first one, do this:

```
{{:contacts[0].firstName}}
```

Otherwise you need a loop using the for tag.